# Why do we need horizontal flip to represent this frieze group?

Tags: group-theory

[image: Frieze group]

[image]

Given this group. Book writes that we need glide reflection and horizontal flip to represent this group. However i think we only need glide reflection. What's the need for horizontal flip in this case ? Also in Cayley diagram why the arrows are in reverse direction in the in the bottom part of the diagram comparison to top part  ?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's label these..

> $$\cdots\qquad\langle 1\rangle\qquad\qquad \langle 3\rangle\qquad\qquad\langle 5\rangle\qquad \cdots$$
>
> ---
>
> $$\qquad\cdots\qquad\langle 2\rangle\qquad\qquad\langle 4\rangle \qquad\cdots$$

With glide reflections, we can, say, move $\langle 1\rangle$ to $\langle 2\rangle$, $\langle 2\rangle$ to $\langle 3\rangle$, and so on. *However* we cannot, say, glide reflect $\langle 1\rangle$ to $\langle 5\rangle$, $\langle 2\rangle$ to $\langle 4\rangle$, etc., while keeping $\langle 3\rangle$ fixed even though this is a symmetry of the image because glide reflections do not have any fixed points.

Does that make sense?

Comment: i don't understand if we can go from 1 to 2 then 2 to 3 then 3 to 4 then 4 to 5 then  we can cover everything . can't we ?

Comment: No because that is not the only symmetry of the image. You can reflect across the midline of any of the diamonds and the image will be the same. That cannot possibly be captured by the glide reflections.

Comment: If we can use glide reflection to go from 1 to 5 and also we can use horizontal flip to go from 1 o 5 then why do we need both ?

Comment: In your second line, shouldnot it be 2 to 4 instead of 2 to 3?

Comment: i have edited the question. Maybe it explains better now my question

Comment: Ah yep good observation. The reason you need both is not just that 1->5 but also simultaneously 2->4 which you cannot possibly do with glide reflections.

Comment: So you mean to say that in order to simultaneously go from 1 to 5 and 2 to 4 we need horizontal shift ? also why do we need to keep <3> fixed ? i mean why fix something at all

Comment: Because that's a symmetry of the image.. I don't know how much clearer it can be unfortunately. Imagine flipping the entire image around. You get the same image, thus making it a symmetry and thus part of the frieze group.

Comment: can you explain Cayley diagram of this.